# Liquibase from JPA classes, no database yet

Tags: jpa, liquibase

We have started our application by our model classes, annotated with JPA annotations. We did not create any tables in the database yet.

Now, we would like to somehow generate a liquibase changelog by only looking at the JPA classes, maybe at file persistence.xml.

Most of the questions and answers about liquibase in SO suggest to run liquibase and compare it with the current state of the database. But that's not our case, because our database does not have any of the tables corresponding to the JPA entities, nor any of the liquibase control tables.

How do I generate a liquibase changelog file from the JPA entities?

Answer (score 1):

you can take a look on liquibase-hibernate plugin https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-hibernate/wiki

you can make a diff between your JPA entities against an empty database , and this will generate the whole changelog of the JPA entities..